# Getting the highest value of a column in MongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-ruby

I've been for some help on getting the highest value on a column for a mongo document. I can sort it and get the top/bottom, but I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do it.

I tried the following (and different combinations):

```
transactions.find("id" => x).max({"sellprice" => 0})
```

But it keeps throwing errors. What's a good way to do it besides sorting and getting the top/bottom?

Thank you!

Comment: You should include the errors it's throwing.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

max() does not work the way you would expect it to in SQL for Mongo.  This is perhaps going to change in future versions but as of now, max,min are to be used with indexed keys primarily internally for sharding.

see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/min+and+max+Query+Specifiers

Unfortunately for now the only way to get the max value is to sort the collection desc on that value and take the first.

```
transactions.find("id" => x).sort({"sellprice" => -1}).limit(1).first()
```

Answer (score 19):

Sorting might be overkill. You can just do a group by

```
db.messages.group(
           {key: { created_at:true },
            cond: { active:1 },
            reduce: function(obj,prev) { if(prev.cmax<obj.created_at) prev.cmax = obj.created_at; },
            initial: { cmax: **any one value** }
            });
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an overkill considering [this quote from the manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) *"When a $sort immediately precedes a $limit in the pipeline, the $sort operation only maintains the top n results as it progresses, where n is the specified limit"*

Answer (score 10):

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
  {
    $group : 
    {
      _id  : "",
      last : 
      {
        $max : "$sellprice"
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Example mongodb shell code for computing aggregates.

see mongodb manual entry for group (many applications) :: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#stage._S_group

In the below, replace the $vars with your collection key and target variable.

```
db.activity.aggregate( 
  { $group : {
      _id:"$your_collection_key", 
      min: {$min : "$your_target_variable"}, 
      max: {$max : "$your_target_variable"}
    }
  } 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use aggregate():

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  {$match: {id: x}},
  {$sort: {sellprice:-1}},
  {$limit: 1},
  {$project: {sellprice: 1}}
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

It will work as per your requirement.

```
transactions.find("id" => x).sort({"sellprice" => -1}).limit(1).first()
```

Comment: What's the point of this answer? Repeating the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

If the column's indexed then a sort should be OK, assuming Mongo just uses the index to get an ordered collection. Otherwise it's more efficient to iterate over the collection, keeping note of the largest value seen. e.g.

```
max = nil
coll.find("id" => x).each do |doc| 
    if max == nil or doc['sellprice'] > max then
        max = doc['sellprice'] 
    end
end
```

(Apologies if my Ruby's a bit ropey, I haven't used it for a long time - but the general approach should be clear from the code.)

Comment: Consider to iterate with MapReduce !!! This why MongoDB is cool, else use flat files ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I was using the Ruby driver (I saw a mongodb-ruby tag on the bottom), I'd do something like the following if I wanted to get the maximum `_id` (assuming my `_id` is sortable). In my implementation, my `_id` was an integer.

```
result = my_collection.find({}, :sort => ['_id', :desc]).limit(1)
```

To get the minimum `_id` in the collection, just change `:desc` to `:asc`

Comment: Wouldn't find_one() be better than using limit()?

`result = my_collection.find_one({}, :sort => ['_id', :desc])`

Answer (score 0):

Following query does the same thing:
    `db.student.find({}, {'_id':1}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)`

For me, this produced following result:
`{ "_id" : NumberLong(10934) }`