# mongodb: finding the highest numeric value of a column

Tags: php, mongodb, find

I have MongoDB collection of documents containing several fields. One of the columns/fields should be numeric only, but some of these fields contain non-numerical (corrupt) data as string values. I should find the highest numerical value of this column, excluding the corrupt, non-numerical data. I am aware of the question [Getting the highest value of a column in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762980/getting-the-highest-value-of-a-column-in-mongodb), but AFAIK, this extended case was not covered.

The example below depicts the issue. For the highest value, the document with `"age": 70` should be returned:

```
[
{
    "id": "aa001",
    "age": "90"
},
{
    "id": "bb002",
    "age": 70
},
{
    "id": "cc003",
    "age": 20,
}
]
```

Providing a PHP example for the find() / findOne() query would be of much help. Thanks a lot!

JohnnyHK came up with the perfect solution. Here's the working PHP code:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('age' => array('$not' => array('$type' => 2))), array('age' => 1));
$cursor->sort(array('age' => -1))->limit(1);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`$type`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/#_S_type) operator with [`$not`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/not/#_S_not) in your query to exclude docs where `age` is a string.  In the shell your query would look like:

```js
db.test.find({age: {$not: {$type: 2}}}).sort({age: -1}).limit(1)
```

Or in PHP from Martti:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('age' => array('$not' => array('$type' => 2))), array('age' => 1));
$cursor->sort(array('price' => -1))->limit(1);
```

Comment: Wow that was fast, thanks! Works perfectly. I'll add the working related PHP code to the question.

Answer (score 7):

**with PHP driver (mongodb)**
using `findOne()`

```
$filter=[];
$options = ['sort' => ['age' => -1]]; // -1 is for DESC
$result = $collection->findOne(filter, $options);
$maxAge = $result['age']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate function to get maximum number from collections like this.

```
$data=$collection->aggregate(array
                    ( '$group'=> 
                        array('_id'=>'',
                            'age'=>array('$max'=>'$age'.)
                        )
                    )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$options = ['limit' => 100,'skip' => 0, 'projection' => ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']], 'sort' => ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']]];
```