# MongoDB - Get highest value of child

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get the highest value of a child value. If I have two documents like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5585b8359557d21f44e1d857"),
    "test" : {
        "number" : 1,
        "number2" : 1
    }
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5585b8569557d21f44e1d858"),
    "test" : {
        "number" : 2,
        "number2" : 1
    }
}
```

How would I get the highest value of key "number"?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762980/getting-the-highest-value-of-a-column-in-mongodb . I think it's not duplicate just because that you want to get the child max value and not the max of a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dot notation:

```
db.testSOF.find().sort({'test.number': -1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: You should also do `.first()`, otherwise you just get a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

> `max()` does not work the way you would expect it to in SQL for Mongo.
>   This is perhaps going to change in future versions but as of now,
>   max,min are to be used with indexed keys primarily internally for
>   sharding.
>
> see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/min+and+max+Query+Specifiers
>
> Unfortunately for now the only way to get the max value is to sort the
>   collection desc on that value and take the first.
>
> ```
> db.collection.find("_id" => x).sort({"test.number" => -1}).limit(1).first()
> ```

quoted from: [Getting the highest value of a column in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762980/getting-the-highest-value-of-a-column-in-mongodb?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

To get the highest value of the key "number" you could use two approaches here. You could use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** where the pipeline would look like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "max_number": {
                "$max": "$test.number"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "max_number" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

or you could use the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find)** cursor as follows

```
db.collection.find().sort({"test.number": -1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: @XLordalX Yes. You can see the AsyaKamsky's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22122161/3136474

Comment: Thanks @DineiA.Rockenbach for the reference, great answer with some good explanations.